# Mistake in Peter Lax Linear Algebra Caley Hamilton proof

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

This is with reference to the Proof of Cayley Hamilton theorem on Page 68 of Peter Lax Linear algebra and its application (second edition)

Equation 21 reads

> According to formula 30 of Chapter 5

$$ P(s)Q(s) = det Q(s) I = P_A(s)I $$

Formula 30 in chapter 5 is actually the formula for the inverse of a matrix. So It is clear that $P(s)$ and $Q(s)$ are *matrices whose elements are polynomials of $s$*. Specifically, $P(s)$ is the matrix of cofactors of $Q(s)$

He goes on to invoke lemma 6 which states that

> If P and Q are two polynomials with matrix coefficients...

So clearly the substitution is invalid, because in equation 21, $P(s)$ is a matrix whose elements are polynomials of $s$, whereas in Lemma 6, $P(s)$ is a polynomial of $s$ with matrix coefficients.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A_k=(a_{i,j}^{(k)})$ are matrices of the same size then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}A_ks^k=\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_{i,j}^{(k)}s^k\right)$$

The LHS is a polynomial with $A_k$ as coefficients and the RHS is a matrix with polynomial entries.

Comment: Thanks for making it explicit :) I think you're missing the $s^k$ factor on the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix whose entries are polynomials in $s$ and a polynomial in $s$ whose coefficients are scalar matrices are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, now I see light :) It would still have been good for the text to indicate this for simpletons like me :)